# R - Chi Square Independence Test with same probabilites for classes

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

#### Edit:

*As I found later somewhere else, the Chi² test is probably not appropriate for my data here or rather does not test what I want to find out. Therefore, I conducted a generalised linear model (glm) with a Poisson distribution on my data which worked out quite nicely. So bear this in mind...*

.

After consulting various websites on this problem (like [this](https://mgimond.github.io/Stats-in-R/ChiSquare_test.html), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85861/what-is-wrong-with-this-chi-squared-calculation/85906#85906) or [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-test-of-independence-in-r)) and of course the official documentation of the [`chisq.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/chisq.test.html) function, I still cannot figure out a solution to my problem.

### What I want:

I want to conduct a Chi² Test of Independence on my data via the `chisq.test` function in `R`. My data is composed of 4 epiphyte species found on 4 host tree species (that means: plants of 4 species growing ON these 4 tree species). Now, I want to find out if the epiphytes are equally distributed among those trees or if maybe one tree species tends to host more epiphyte individuals as the others. The standard Chi² test I can conduct quite easily (see below). But this would then as well test if epiphyte species were equally distributed, which I don't want to be tested. So, how can I submit different probabilities for my contingency table in the `cisq.test` function? Namely, I want the expected matrix to be according to the number of epiphyte individuals per species while expecting them to be equally distributed among the tree species. This sounds complicated, so just have a look at my example data:

### Example Data:

(I edited the data format as suggested by @paoloeusebi)

#### Observed data:

```
obs_data = matrix(c(0,60,2,5,
                 0,25,3,5,
                 20,90,30,
                 10,1,4,3,0),
               nrow = 4, 
               dimnames = list(c("AS", "BU", "CL", "MB"),
                               c("CS", "GS", "TA", "WG")))

> obs_data
   CS GS TA WG
1    AS  0  0 20  1
2    BU 60 25 90  4
3    CL  2  3 30  3
4    MB  5  5 10  0
```

#### Expected data:

Creating the expected data:

```
exp_data = matrix(rep(colSums(obs_data)/4,each = 4),
                  nrow = 4,
                  dimnames = list(c("AS", "BU", "CL", "MB"),
                                  c("CS", "GS", "TA", "WG")))

> exp_data
      CS   GS   TA WG
AS 16.75 8.25 37.5  2
BU 16.75 8.25 37.5  2
CL 16.75 8.25 37.5  2
MB 16.75 8.25 37.5  2
```

#### BUT: Expected data according to Chi² test:

```
> example_test = chisq.test(obs_data[,2:4])

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  obs_data[, 2:4]
X-squared = 31.99, df = 6, p-value = 1.639e-05

> example_test$expected
        CS    GS  TA
[1,]  5.36  2.64  12
[2,] 46.90 23.10 105
[3,]  9.38  4.62  21
[4,]  5.36  2.64  12
```

### Question

So, is this even the right test for what I want to do? Maybe I should just do a goodness-of-fit Chi² test with the melted/long data? But I am not sure if this would be accurate.

### Solution as suggested by @paoloeusebi:

I did the Chi² test by hand by using my own expected data instead of the standard one. Don't know if that is ok for this test though...

```
> chi_result_own = sum((obs_data-exp_data)^2/exp_data)
[1] 304.8688

> pchisq(chi_result_own, df = 9, lower.tail = F)
[1] 2.419579e-60
```

And that is apparently just the same as doing the goodness-of-fit Chi²? However, the p-value is much lower and the df are different while the Chi²-value is the same!?

```
long_data = obs_data %>% melt()
long_exp = exp_data %>% melt() %>% mutate(value = value/sum(value))

> chisq.test(long_data$value, p = long_exp$value)

Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  long_data$value
X-squared = 304.87, df = 15, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to input data as matrix instead as data frame.

```
obs_data <- matrix(c(0,60,2,5,
                     0,25,3,5,
                     20,90,30,
                     10,1,4,3,0),
                     nrow = 4, 
                     dimnames = list(c("AS", "BU", "CL", "MB"),
                                     c("CS", "GS", "TA", "WG")))
obs_data
       CS GS TA WG
   AS  0  0 20  1
   BU 60 25 90  4
   CL  2  3 30  3
   MB  5  5 10  0
```

In what follows I use the same calculus of the chi-square test function.
Expected cell counts are matrix product of marginal totals (rows and columns) divided by the total.

```
sr <- rowSums(obs_data)
sc <- colSums(obs_data)
exp_data <- outer(sr, sc, "*")/sum(obs_data)

exp_data
        CS        GS        TA        WG
    AS  5.453488  2.686047  12.20930 0.6511628
    BU 46.484496 22.895349 104.06977 5.5503876
    CL  9.868217  4.860465  22.09302 1.1782946
    MB  5.193798  2.558140  11.62791 0.6201550
```

This is what is needed to calculate the value of Chi2 distribution

```
sum((obs_data-exp_data)^2/exp_data)
[1] 35.57418
pchisq(35.574, df=(nrow(obs_data)-1)*(ncol(obs_data)-1), lower.tail = F)
[1] 4.717395e-05
```

Which is the same calculated by the chisq.test function

```
chisq.test(obs_data)
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  obs_data
X-squared = 35.574, df = 9, p-value = 4.717e-05
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my question was not how I could compute the expected Chi² matrix by hand. Rather, I want to feed the Chi² somehow my own expected matrix so that the hypothesis is different (like if were to do a goodness-of-fit Chi² with `chisq.test` while giving the `p` parameter). Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, could you check the updated version of the answer?

Comment: Ah, you mean I could just throw in my expected matrix instead and calculate the Chi² by hand? I'll try that...

Comment: Yes, otherwise you can put your expected values in the argument p of the chisq.test